# Avoiding redundant Bundler dependency declarations for Rack

Tags: sinatra, bundler, rack

Imagine a Rack application that, on startup, creates instances of some other Ruby applications and maps routes to those applications.  This application has a Rack dependency of 1.2.2.

Now imagine we're developing a sub-application which will be run by this application.  It has a Sinatra dependency of 1.2.6 and uses Bundler.  It's gemfile is a barren:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem "sinatra", "1.2.6"
```

Unfortunately, when we `bundle install` this sub-application, Bundler, with no knowledge of the Rack 1.2.2 dependency of the parent application, will install the most recent version of Rack that is compatible with Sinatra 1.2.6: currently 1.3.2.  Our Gemfile.lock will be:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    rack (1.3.2)
    sinatra (1.2.6)
       rack (~> 1.1)
       tilt (< 2.0, >= 1.2.2)
    tilt (1.3.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
   sinatra (= 1.2.6)
```

When we try to start the parent application (which starts our sub-application), we'll get:

`You have already activated rack 1.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.3.2. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)`

What is the correct way to handle this situation?  Yes, we could explicitly require rack 1.2.2, but we'd effectively be stating a dependency of a dependency.  I'd imagine that, ideally, the parent application would be a gem which our sub-application would require, but in this situation, we don't have the ability to make it so.

Comment: How do you start your sub-application exactly? `bundle exec rackup` might be a good idea to stick with locked dependencies

Comment: I guess the "best" way is to update your parent application so it doesn't require an "old" version of Rack.

Answer (score 1):

Your "main" process should use `bundle exec` to launch the subprocesses, just as the error message recommends.

That will force the new app to launch within it's *own* `Gemfile`'s bundle context, not the global gem context.  As a result, the new app will be launched using Rack 1.3.2 or later, *not* Rack 1.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete Rack 1.2.2 from gem local